# Android: Problems loading images

Tags: android, performance, bitmap, drawable

<strike>I have bigs problems with the decodeSampleBitmap code and the final size of my images. I have my drawables in nodpi drawables folder for not multiply the same drawable in diferents folders with diferents sizes, and i resize after aply my decodeSampleBitmap.</strike>

I have this code for load a bitmap:

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }
    return inSampleSize;
}

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}
```

The code i can get at the documentation. Ok i think this is for load images more eficiently but i have memory problems. I try explain this problem.

1-I want load a png, 2037x1440 pixels, 12.6kb.

2-I aply my code and load a png with 2037x1440 pixels and 11,73 MB. I dont undurstand what i'm doing wrong. Why android multiply for 1000 the size of my drawables?

```
10-12 12:06:07.842 12405-12822/com.viridesoft.kiseichuu V/control4: width=2037 height=1440 size=11733120
```

Edit: if i load the drawable with BitmapFactory.decodeResource the size is the same, 11733120.

The old question should be changed. I understand i cant reduce more my image size and i continue with the same problem.

I load a lot of images for create a dinamical background and charge all the characters(my player and zombies), in total until 111 bitmaps of 25%px x 10%px of the screen size and until 30 bitmaps of the 100% screen size. I load all this bitmaps in a loader activity and save for the later use in the game. I have a good quality of images and a drawable-nodpi folder with a lot of images for the best android resolution i see. My game run fluid in some devices (bq aquaris, nexus 5, etc) but is continually cleaning the memory and run slow in others (some tablets, some mid-range devices, etc )

The new question is:
How i can load eficiently a lot of images for a fluid game experiencie?

Comment: What exactly is 11,73 MB? And where exactly did you determine the final resolution? Which value do you calculate for `inSampleSize`?

Comment: `reqWidth, reqHeight` Which values do you request?

Comment: i pass this values for sample 1280x720 but you can see the bitmap width and height than my code return, with 11733120 bytes, i request the screen width and height

Comment: You should give exact figures to begin with. Tell all the values i asked. And answer all my questions! I still do not know where that 11,73 MB comes from.

Comment: `if i load the drawable with BitmapFactory.decodeResource the size is the same` ??? well you ARE using BitmapFactory.decodeResource(). Nothing else. So what do you mean?

Comment: greenapps, i use the code form this documentation https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html. I request the vaules, in this example of the screen, 1024x720 . I try using BitmapFactory.decodeResource() for see the diference with the size. For know the size of my bitmap i use bmp.getAllocationByteCount().

Comment: Sorry but why are your answers so not to the point? And why dont you tell what you calculated for `inSampleSize`? `getAllocationByteCount` does you tell the wrong size of course. Whatever size you have in mind. The only thing that you could say is that the original is 2037x1440 and that decodeResource delivers a 2037x1440 too. So it is NOT resized. So what do you calculate for inSampleSize?

Comment: greenapps, i dont understund what do you want. i answer you, i calculate my bitmaps for my game inSampleSize using the the GOOGLE CODE, i cant tell you more. IDK what is worng, i cant tell you what is wrong because i'm asking for know what is the problem. I dont speak english very well and try answer you. If getAllocationByteCount dont tell me the correct size, why my memory error tell me fail to allocate similar size?

Comment: `i calculate my bitmaps for my game inSampleSize` Yes i know that. But what do you get? 1? 2? 3? WHAT DO YOU GET? What value?  How many times do i have to ask that yet again?

Comment: I had not understood the question, i dont use a fix value, i calcule 
automatically for my bitmaps of all game. i get a value of 1 the items crash the aplication, and please, you do not get angry, i not speak very well english and i can dont not understand you.

Comment: If `inSampleSize==1` then why are you amazed that both BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, id)
 and BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, id, opts) with opts using inSampleSize== 1
 deliver the same original bitmap of 2037x1440 ?

Comment: And the memory error and the crash are new. Crashes you can avoid with using try{}catch{} and you always shoud check if decodeResource() delivers a null pointer instead of a valid bitmap. You did not tell which statement causes your app to crash. So it's time you do. Post the logcat.

Comment: i solved the crash problems, my app crash with a outOfMemory and i resize a little the images for get the sames pixels of the screen, but continue chargin the images of 12kb with 2 MB, my game cant run fluidly with 2mb images, i use for my game one background with fix back and between 8 and 16 adorments, if each adorment have 2mb the app run in same devices so slow. I continue with the same problem, i use the code decodeSampledBitmapFromResource and i get a bmp with excesive size.

Comment: Why do you call that excessive? You should know that Bitmaps occupy a lot of memory. At least ten times as much as a png ot jpg file on disk. The only chance you have to avoid memory problems is to resize to lower resolution. You are now using inSampleSize==1. And you get a non resized bimage. The original image. Why are you calling that excessive? You did not resize it at all.

Comment: If your app gets slow then that is only possible if you resize on the main thread. Use threads for it.

Comment: but with my calculations i'm loading a image with a proportion 1000 to 1 in size, this is excesive i think, or this is the real memory usage?

Comment: i explain my app, i load all images befor the game, and save in a object with all the bitmaps, then in game i use the bitmaps, not load, only use the bitmaps.

Comment: `and save in a object with all the bitmaps`. Imagine how much memory you claim from the system if every image is already 10MB. Well 100MB still would not be much... but if you have memory problems i would not do that.

Comment: Calculate yourself: pixels*colors: 2037x1440*4= 11.733.120 bytes occupied.

Comment: ok, the size is correct, in 1 hour i change the code and tell you if my problem is solved. I have 120mb allocated in my tablet with 20 decorations, 2 backgrounds, 1 player with 56 frames of 200x140px and 3 enemies with 45 frames of 200x140px and all in full resolution, i think i'm in the good way